# model:forward() in lua file showing segmentation fault while loading a model using lua for the first time

Tags: python, lua

I am a newbie,tying to implement this model https://github.com/MLSpeech/DeepFormants
Facing segmentation fault ,after local myPrediction = model:forward(X)  (check the image above)
Any help will be appreciated

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qhJ3E.png)

Here is the formants.py

import extract_features as features
import argparse
from helpers.textgrid import *
from helpers.utilities import *
import shutil

def predict_from_times(wav_filename, preds_filename, begin, end):
    tmp_features_filename = tempfile._get_default_tempdir() + "/" + next(tempfile._get_candidate_names()) + ".txt"
    print (tmp_features_filename)

```
if begin > 0.0 or end > 0.0:
    features.create_features(wav_filename, tmp_features_filename, begin, end)
    easy_call("th load_estimation_model.lua " + tmp_features_filename + ' ' + preds_filename)
else:
    features.create_features(wav_filename, tmp_features_filename)
    easy_call("th load_tracking_model.lua " + tmp_features_filename + ' ' + preds_filename)
```

and here is the image for the execution of the given command
python formants.py data/Example.wav data/ExamplePredictions.csv --begin 1.2 --end 1.3
[core dumped
output 1 and 2 are due to purpose of debugging](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jdkHI.png)

Comment: Can you add the code in the image to your post? it helps us test your problem so we can reproduce the error. with just the image we have to reproduce the code from the image which takes more time and you're not likely to get as much help.

Comment: Can you check it please